Resizable corner won't appear on img, despite `resize: both` in the CSS
I'm working on an online notepad tool and it uses a contenteditable div to store text.
Since pasting images works, I tried adding the resize property to all img elements, but the resize corner won't appear. I compared my code with the W3Schools demo; for some reason, the broken image is resizable while the loaded image can't be resized.


div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 75%;
}

img {
  border: solid 2px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  width: 50px;
}
<div contenteditable="true">
  <img src="e">
  <img src="https://nunnerrs.github.io/notepad/assets/sketchy-happy.png">
</div>




"[The] broken image is resizable..." - not for me, in Firefox 133 on Windows 11.

You cannot apply resize to inline elements (see developer docs) and img is listed as an inline element (see w3schools list).
Therefore, you could wrap your images in a resizable div:


div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 75%;
}

.resizable{
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: min-content;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: min-content;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
<div contenteditable="true">
  <div class="resizable">
    <img src="e" />
  </div>
  <div class="resizable">
    <img src="https://nunnerrs.github.io/notepad/assets/sketchy-happy.png" />
  </div>
</div>



